# centosでのpythonの入れ直しのやり方が分かりません。

Tags: python, python3, centos

centosでのpythonの入れ直しのやり方が分かりません。
centos上にpython3を入れたのですが、sqliteを先に入れるのを忘れていた為、
pythonを入れ直しを行わないといけないそうなのですが、うまくアンインストールが出来ません。

どうすればいいのでしょうか？
　　　
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

追記
python3.9のインストールは、下記のサイトに従いインストールを行いました。
https://mebee.info/2021/02/24/post-29350/

```
which python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

---

追記
pythonを入れ直しをしましたが、うまく行きませんでした。
sqliteがインストール出来ていないのかの確認を行いました。

```
[jirow04@jirow04 centos 初期インストール設定]$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jirow04/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jirow04/.local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/home/jirow04/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/home/jirow04/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
[jirow04@jirow04 centos 初期インストール設定]$ sqlite -V
bash: sqlite: コマンドが見つかりませんでした...
[jirow04@jirow04 centos 初期インストール設定]$ sqlite
bash: sqlite: コマンドが見つかりませんでした...
[jirow04@jirow04 centos 初期インストール設定]$ ^C
[jirow04@jirow04 centos 初期インストール設定]$ sqlite3 --version
3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668
```

Comment: CentOS 標準のパッケージでは Python 2.x のはずなので、ソースコードからインストールした Python ではありませんか？ `which python3.9` の結果を質問文に貼り付けてみてください。

Comment: 「ソースコードからのインストール」「sqlite を有効にしたい」といった辺りの情報をタイトルや本文で明確にすべきかと